# Modifying parameters with code in Microsoft Reporting Services

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I made a report with about 30 different rectangles and textboxes that have different visibility expressions depending on the parameters.  (It's a student invoice and many different messages have to appear depending on the semester)  When I made all the expressions I coded in the parameters in all upper case.  Now I have a problem when users enter lowercase letters, the SQL all works fine since it is not case sensitive, but the different rectangles and textboxes don't show. Is there a way in the report code to first capitalize all the parameters before running the SQL? Or do I actually have to go back to every visibility expression and add separate iif's for upper and lower case? (That seems incredibly silly to have to do). I can't change my parameters to numbers because I have been given strict requirements for input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if this is the most elegant solution, but you could accomplish this by following this procedure for every parameter on the Report Parameters page:

1)Re-name the parameter, leaving its prompt as that of the old parameter.

2)Add a new parameter with the same name as the old parameter.

3)Mark this new parameter as Hidden.

4)Make sure that the new parameter's available values are marked as non-queried(available values will never be actually used.)

5)Mark the Default Values as Non-queried, using the following syntax:
=ucase(Parameters!OldParameterName.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just UCASE the params (do it in the xml view, it will be quicker and you might even be able to do a regex find/replace)